# appium script starting off

Tags: android, python, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have installed appium. I want to use it with android apps using Python on a win 7 machine. I do not know how to start a script off to use appium and do not know to use Python IDLE or something else? I have checked examples and discussion groups and found them not helpful. If there is better examples on how to use appium this would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Yes you can use the IDLE. You use appium as a server. A better version will be released with Selenium 3 Christmas of 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some links to get started provided from people working on Appium. Some documentation is not up to date since this is still pre Appium 1.0 but should be updated by May 1st.

http://appium.github.io/training/

https://github.com/appium/appium/tree/master/docs